# Fetch specific array element data using variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to locate data in an array by using value identifiers?

Example: In the object below, I want to do something similar to:

```
for(country in data.countries)
{
    if(country.name === "GB") {return-value-of-country.Clear;}
}
```

Object example:

```
 {
  "countries":[
    {
      "name": "GB",
      "Rain":" url1 ",
      "Clear":" url2 "
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: `countries` here is an Array, so use index to select specific country before calling `.name` on top of it

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using ES6 or some external library there's not a great way to do it, something like:

```
var countries = data.countries,
    len = countries.length,
    match, i, country;

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    country = countries[i];
    if (country.name === 'GB') {
        match = country;
        break;
    }
}

if (match) {
    console.log(match.Clear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over array you need for loop with index:

```
for(var i = 0; i<data.countries.length; ++i) {
    if(data.countries[i].name === "GB") {
        //your value is data.countries[i].Clear;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

I would do something like:

```js
var test = {
  "countries":[
    {
      "name": "GB",
      "Rain":" url1_gb",
      "Clear":" url2_gb"
    },
    {
      "name": "FR",
      "Rain":" url1_fr",
      "Clear":" url2_fr"
    },
    {
      "name": "DE",
      "Rain":" url1_de",
      "Clear":" url2_de"
    },

  ]
}

var getClearUrl = function(country) {
  for (var i = test.countries.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (test.countries[i].name === country) {
      return test.countries[i].Clear;
      break;
    }
  };  

  return false;
}

var clearUrlGB = getClearUrl('GB');
console.log(clearUrlGB);
```